# "The layout "layout" in layout-land has no declaration in the base `layout` folder (..)"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, responsive-design, constraints

I've set up a video showcase, that plays a specific video when the attached image button is pressed.
However, I'm having some issues with portrait and landscape modes.

In an attempt to solve this, I followed several threads on here and created a "layout-land" folder with a layout.xml, then copy-pasted everything from the activity_main.xml file.

However, I still can't get the app to recognize and use the land layout when tilting the phone or tablet, and the only error I have is this:

> "The layout "layout" in layout-land has no declaration in the base
> `layout` folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried
> in a configuration that does not match this qualifier"*

**So far I've tried:** Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V on the XML text. gradle sync, invalidate cache, app+pc restart and changing the XML file ID to match.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="520dp"
    android:onClick="Click1"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="170dp"
    android:onClick="Click2"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/videoView1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
    android:onClick="Click3"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="520dp"
    android:onClick="Click4"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

**PS.** How do I get proper colors in my code snippets? First time I'm using it.

Comment: The layout file should still have the same name in other folder: `activity_main.xml`, not `layout.xml`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the prompt response. I tried renaming the landscape layout file to activity_main, but got this warning "resource @layout/activity_main already exists"

Comment: Is it preventing you from renaming? Or is it just reminding you that you already have such a file?

Comment: It was just a warning apparently, I ignored it and renamed & now it all works like a charm. Thanks a bunch, Mike! - How do I give you the answer accepted checkmark?

Comment: Yeah, I just went through the same steps to check; it was only a heads up. No problem! Nothin' huge, though. Thanks for the offer. Feel free to finish this up however you like. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All credits to @Mike M's comment.**

The *landscape.xml* file has to be named the same as the original *activity_main.xml* file for the tilt to work.
Just ignore Android Studio's warnings and complaints when renaming.